# Xcode compact Width and Regular Height not showing

Tags: xcode

In my xcode storyboard, compact Width and Regular Height not showing as screen below.

Deployment target is 7.1, Device is iPhone and Landscape left/right are already checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer is we need to enable size classes in storyboard as per Apple's resources.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH1-SW1